# Dispatching URLs through Flask without a TCP port

Tags: python, webkit, flask, hybrid

I want to build a hybrid application (Web technologies embedded in a desktop app).

I will start with a Web version and the embed it using WebKit, but I don't want the embedded version to service requests through a TCP port.

With WebKit (Qt,Gtk) I can intercept all URL requests and act on them.

What I'm missing is a way to invoke the Flask URL-to-callable dispatcher without going through TCP (or WSGI).

Any ideas better than analyzing the call stack with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simon Sapin answered on the (quite active) Flask mailing list:

> Why not WSGI ?
>
> You have to get a Python interpreter somewhere. Then you need to call
>   your application somehow with data from WebKit like the URL being
>   requested, and get the response. WSGI is just that: a calling
>   convention for Python functions (or other callable objects.)
>
> If WSGI is more complex than you’d like, you can use the test client:
>
> - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.test_client
> - http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/#werkzeug.test.Client
> - http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder
>
> That’s how I do it in Frozen-Flask. It simulates HTTP requests to a
>   Flask app at the WSGI level and write the responses to static files.
>   The test client is just an easier way to make WSGI calls:
>
> [`https://github.com/SimonSapin/Frozen-Flask/blob/master/flaskext/frozen/__init__.py#L228`](https://github.com/SimonSapin/Frozen-Flask/blob/master/flaskext/frozen/__init__.py#L228)
>
> WSGI really is Flask’s "entry point".
>
> Other than that if you’re interested in Flask inner workings start
>   looking from here:
>
> https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1477